# Trying to use setType and getting Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const CreateTweet = () => {
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState();
  const [tweets, setTweets] = useState();

  const userInputHandler = (e: any) => {
    setTextInput(e.target.value);
  };
  const submitTweetHandler = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTweets([...tweets, textInput]); //This is where the error is happening : Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.
  Type 'any[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.
    setTextInput(""); //and down here : Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitTweetHandler}>
      <textarea
        value={textInput} /* connects the value to the form box */
        onChange={userInputHandler}
        cols={50}
        rows={5}
      ></textarea>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CreateTweet;
```

I have been trying to get this to work, it runs in javascript but for some reason I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement this setTweets function on typescript. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to type the `useState`s properly. Since the `textInput` is a string, you should set it to be the empty string initially, and since `tweets` will be an array of strings, type that as an array of strings as well:

```
const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');
const [tweets, setTweets] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
```

Comment: I was wondering, why not - `const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState<string>('');` for `textInput` state. Does it consider it as `string` implicitly?

Comment: Yes, if you pass something of type T into `useState`, TypeScript will assume that to be the type of the state. But if the initial value doesn't provide enough type information (eg, `tweets` being an array of strings), you'll need to note the type explicitly.